# Faça uma função que receba uma matriz A(10,10) e retorna um vetor com a soma de cada uma das linhas de A

Tags: c, funções, matriz

Estou tentando resolver esse problema.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
/* 
 5. Faça uma função que receba uma matriz A(10,10) e retorna um vetor com a soma de cada uma das linhas de A.
*/


int matriz[3][3];


void soma() {
    int i, j;   
    int soma[3];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            soma[i] = soma[i] + matriz[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\nResultado da soma da linha %d: %d", i+1, soma[i]);
    }

}


int main() {
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("Digite o valor da posicao %d %d: ", i+1, j+1);  
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

    soma();
}
```

Comment: Não inclua apenas o código do seu problema. Qual é o erro que você esta obtendo? O que você esperava obter? O que você já tentou? Não temos como ler sua mente!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente o seu método deve receber a matriz, então em sua declaração deve ser.

```
int *soma(int **matriz){
    /*...*/
}
```

`int *` diz que seu método irá retornar um vetor, e `int **` diz que o parâmetro a receber será uma matriz.

Não é muito legal ficar usando variáveis globais, isso não deixa seu código muito organizado. Então sua matriz deve ser construída dentro do `main`, assim se encaixa no escopo da pergunta.

```
void main(){
    int matriz[10][10];
    int i,j;
    /*...*/
}
```

E ainda dentro do `main`, deverá ter o retorno para uma variável, que será seu vetor.

```
int *vetor = soma(matriz);
```

E em `soma`, deve criar o seu vetor.

```
int *vetor_soma = malloc(sizeof(int)*10); // o uso do malloc para criar vetores para retornar é mais seguro que uma declaração estática.
```

E por fim no final do seu método deve efetuar o retorno.

```
return vetor_soma;
```